# JQuery - SSL $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, ssl, https

If I serve a page over SSL, and I do an AJAX post:

```
$.post('/core/somepage.php', ....);
```

Will the post be made via HTTPS, or do I have to put an absolute URL like:

`$.post('https://example.com/core/somepage.php', ....);`

Also, does this apply with :

```
$('#element').load('/core/something.php');
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the post will be made via `https`. Relative paths by definition use the current scheme. Did you know, you can even do something like `//example.com/somepage` if you want to go to an explicit host but keep the current scheme.